# How to toggle the Switch tag using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My objective is to toggle switch off and on as per the respective id, but i couldn't able to toggle the switch.

i have tried in this way:

```
   <Switch
                  checked={data.isShow}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  color="primary"
                  name={data.isShow ? "On" : "Off"}
                  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
                />
```

And OnChange i have written in this way:

```
  handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({ isShow: !this.state.isShow });
  };
```

[Here is the sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-brook-688zh)

Can anyone help me in this query?

Answer (score 1):

You should `handleChange` for specific element. Here I pass the id of the element, and toggle `isShow` of that element only

```
handleChange = (id) => {
  this.setState({
    info: this.state.info.map((i) => {
      if (i.id === id) {
        return {
          ...i,
          isShow: !i.isShow
        };
      } else {
        return i;
      }
    })
  });
};

// ...

<Switch
  checked={data.isShow}
  onChange={() => this.handleChange(data.id)}
  color="primary"
  name={data.isShow ? "On" : "Off"}
  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
/>
```

Forked demo

[image: Edit blissful-goodall-8vpg8]

Answer (score 1):

No need of state variable just update info array in handleChange(). Below are the changes in handleChange() method

```
handleChange = (singleRowData) => {
    console.log(singleRowData);
    const {info} = this.state;
    const index = info.findIndex(data => data.id === singleRowData.id);
    info[index].isShow = !info[index].isShow;
    this.setState({ info: [...info] });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `handleChange` function to:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
let changeId = parseInt(event.target.id);
let info = this.state.info.map((data) => {
  if (data.id === changeId) {
    return Object.assign({}, data, {
      isShow: !data.isShow
    });
  }
  return data;
});
this.setState({info: info});
};
```

Include `id` as part of the Component params

```
<Switch
  checked={data.isShow}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  id={data.id}
  color="primary"
  name={data.isShow ? "On" : "Off"}
  inputProps={{ "aria-label": "primary checkbox" }}
/>
```

Edit:
Made edits to the sample link you've provided - it's working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-wescoff-olrp3?file=/src/Sample.jsx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `isShow` property from the item in the `info` array (in your state).

you can use `find()` in order to find the item with the same `id`, 
but before that you need to use `slice()` to copy `info` array, because you don't mutate your state.

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.

(Referenced from [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state))

your `handleChange()` method should look like this then:

```
handleChange = (id) => {
    const data = this.state.info.slice();
    const item = data.find((item) => item.id === id);
    item.isShow = !item.isShow;
    this.setState(data);
  };
```

Here is the full result: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/async-bird-998ue?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark